# Validator at form level in angular 2

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I want to create a validator for an angular2 form that involves several controls. So far, all I have found is how to create validators for controls inside a form, in an isolated way, like this:

```
this.myControl = new FormControl('',Validators.Required);
```

but I didn't find any example of a validator that involves the state of several controls at the same time.

To explain my case, here is a simple example.
[image: Example]

In this example, what I want is:

- IF the checkbox is selected, I want the two input boxes to be NOT REQUIRED.
- IF the checbox is NOT selected, I want the two input boxes to be REQUIRED.

I could to this programmatically, but I wanted to know if there is an elegant solution that involves validators at a form level, not only at FormControl level.

Comment: You can take a look at this example, it has the custom validator to check if confirm password matches password which is at the formGroup level and involves multiple form controls: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/4607/angular-2-forms/7296/simple-password-change-form-with-multi-control-validattion#t=201609071013388312202

Comment: Thank you very much @HarryNinh but that is not quite what I am lloking for. Again, it doesn't alloz me to check the state of several controls at the same time and also, to decide about whether I want to add or delete Validations on each of them.

Comment: If that doesn't check the state of multiple controls (new password and confirm password) at the same time, I don't know what will. And you don't need to add/remove validations dynamically, you can just check on the control value and either call the validation function on the other control or ignore it.